# rspec/capybara: How to check if cell phone dials a right number (for example after clicking a "tel:" link)

Tags: rspec, capybara

I have a phone number link on the mobile version of my site:

```
<a href="tel:+79162003040">+7 916 200-30-40</a>
```

And I want to write a rspec feature to check if a browser dials the number after clicking this link? I'm pretty sure for the simple link I would just right something like this:

```
page.should have_selector 'a', href: 'tel:+79162003040'
```

But I want to call javascript function to track phone dialing first.